# Facebook Live Video and comments

Tags: facebook, post, video, comments, live

Complete novice in this area and hoping you may be able to point me in the right direction. Would love to see samples/examples of code where possible. Wife sells online through FB Live Videos and rather than paying for CommentSold - as it is overkill - we are looking for a way we can 'push' the names of products into Comments of current live video.

In other words, live video is going; we push a button that populates a comment with the name of the next product (the products would be in some sort of list that would be used to populate comment one at a time and as needed). I was thinking Graph API but couldn't find similar examples.

Comment: What is your Question though? Yes you can use Graph API to make comments. I haven't needed to use it since 2015. See [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/get-started) and then also check the [CommentI](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v13.0/comment) section of the manual. Decide if you are using PHP or Javascript to post the comments.

Comment: Hi. There is no comment section of the manual. The question is; are there any other examples that other users have done similar. I'm sure I'm not the first and without any sort of guide or examples it is hard to determine what direction to head. Connecting the Graph API seems straight forward.

Comment: _"Connecting the Graph API seems straight forward..."_ Are you using Javascript to do everything? Is that the example you need? **PS:** See if these [search results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+facebook+%22post+a+comment%22+-console) are useful to you.

Comment: Thank you! Still looking through the examples but this should be a good start. Much appreciated!!